# Print out check from personal computer

Tags: banking, check, personal-check

For the first time in my life, I have a personal checking account but no paper checks. I have been burned multiple times due to ACH fraud and want to avoid having any thing to do with this 20th century technology. However, I need two checks today to send to the IRS and to my IRA by July 15. How do I print out checks from my computer without buying any software? Is it okay if I just type in my routing number and account number in Photoshop and print it out on plain paper? What about check numbers? Can I just start with 100? Is there any thing else I should be concerned about with printing my own checks without using specialized software or paper?

Comment: As Donald Knuth can attest, using a check does not protect you from ACH fraud.

Comment: So ACH is "20th century technology", but checks are not? Very interesting to see from an European perspective.

Comment: @glglgl: You misread the whole tone of the question.  Checks are the "20th century technology", open to abuse as Brian commented, including abuse of reading the numbers off to submit fraudulent electronic transactions (exactly what Brian is referring to) hence the mention of ACH in the question.  He doesn't want anything to do with checks, however (he claims) that he finds himself forced to use them despite his distaste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I print out checks from my computer without buying any software?

You don't.  [Check printing software](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1330/83) is required for properly printing checks, as well as special-purpose blank check paper.

People often hear stories about handwritten checks written on blank paper or [even on a cow](https://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/562/can-you-write-a-check-on-any-old-piece-of-paper/) and think that they can do that.  The problem, however, is that, while such a check is legal, banks (and consequently, people you want to pay that have to use a bank) understandably do not want to accept checks like this, because of rampant fraud.  They like checks to look legitimate and have [lots of security features](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/103245/10997).  When you are up against a deadline, as you are, you do not want to take the chance that they will reject your check, send it back to you, and you will miss your deadline.

You should be able to take care of this today by going to an office supply store and buying blank check paper, and downloading check printing software.

The check printing software will ask for your routing number and account number, and put it on the check paper in the appropriate place and font.

If you've never used any checks before on your account, you can generally start the check numbers wherever you want.  101 and 1001 are common first check numbers.

---

There are two different types of check printing software programs:

- One type is for starting with blank check stock paper and printing your name and address, the bank's name and address, the check number, and the MICR line, including the routing number and account number.  This software turns blank check stock into blank personalized checks.  Examples of this type of software include [VersaCheck](https://www.versacheck.com/web/) and [ezCheckPrinting](http://www.halfpricesoft.com/check-printing-software.asp).
- The other type of software is what you use after you already have blank personalized checks.  This software fills in the payee, check amount, and memo.  This software is unnecessary if you are writing these in by hand.

Comment: What about MICR toner? I know it's a thing, but I have no idea how widely it's expected.

Comment: @glibdud Magnetic ink is the standard for checks, and magnetic printer ink/toner is available.  However, it is my understanding that most modern check readers are optical, and don't actually require the magnetic ink.  In the past, I have printed checks without special ink, and did not have problems.  (I no longer print my own checks.)  Your mileage may vary.

Comment: According to [MICR Requirement for Checks February 2018](https://x9.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/MICR-Requirement-for-Checks-February-2018.pdf), "_Checks and Substitute Checks (IRDs) are legally required to include a magnetic code line in order to be treated as a “cash item” for processing in the U.S. Payment System._". Whether _in practice_ you can get away without magnetic ink I don't know.

Comment: @TripeHound To be clear, this does not mean that it is illegal to use a check without magnetic ink. What it does mean is that a check without magnetic ink could be considered a [“non-cash item”](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/n/noncash-item.asp), taking longer to clear.

Comment: Of course If the check is scanned by a home scanner, or an picture is uploaded to the bank site, the magnetic ink requirement is easily ignored.

Comment: @BenMiller-RememberMonica: Your point about fraud is valid.  However, recipients who have low fraud concern (e.g., utility companies) tend to be more tolerant of this.  I think the IRS will accept any legally valid paper check, so long as it has all of the required information (you may have to fill in some of it by hand, even if using starter checks).  Though the idea of using check-printing software rather than asking a bank for starter checks (these are basically just home-printed checks) strikes me as a bit odd.  Some banks can even print "proper" checks on demand.

Comment: @Brian I agree with you that printing your own checks does not make sense for most people. (When I did it, it was for a business.) I’m assuming that the OP does not believe he will be able to obtain paper checks any other way by the deadline. In fact, if he hasn’t already sent in that IRA contribution by now, it might be too late.

Comment: So far I have tried to print out a check from two software programs Checkbook Pro and Checkkeeper and both have no option to print the routing and account number. What is going on? I thought you should be able to print a check that can be deposited at a bank.

Comment: @DavidTay I have added an explanation to my answer about why the software you have been using doesn't do what you need it to do.  I agree that it is confusing.  At this late date, you need to contact your IRA custodian/bank, because sending a check now will likely not make it there in time to count for 2019.

Comment: Thanks Ben, it is kind of late, but I figured out Checkeeper was able to print out a check with routing and account numbers. It wasnt obvious at first, but I was able to adjust the template. Thanks for your help.